# Image Segmentation on braTS2020 dataset

Tags: image-segmentation

How does the utilization of both FLAIR MRI scans (niimg) and their corresponding segmentation masks (nimask) from the BraTS20 dataset contribute to the advancement of machine learning models for brain tumor segmentation or classification tasks

In essence, the question aimed to explore the impact and significance of using both FLAIR MRI scans and their corresponding segmentation masks in advancing machine learning models for brain tumor-related tasks